# Edit post again after logging in

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, review-queue

I made an edit to a post, realized I made a mistake but I couldn't edit it again. Then I noticed I was somehow logged out (I'm NEVER logged out normally so it didn't even cross my mind that the button which normally reads 'edit' now read 'improve answer').

I logged in, but I cannot edit because a review is now pending, and I cannot review because I don't have the 2K rep yet.

Can someone find the review and reject it (https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1016139), or is there another trick I can do?

Comment: Why reject it? asterisk is the right word, calling it "the little star" is much more misleading. Your edit is an improvement, I would approve it.

Comment: The edit is gone from the queue now, it was approved, not rejected though. You can re edit it now.

Comment: Ok, that was faster than I expected. FYI the error was in the part after that, unintentionally equating the two executable statements